# How to change .so files accessibility in Android build.gradle file?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, aar

In my Android application, I am working with 2 aar libs. Lets name it as `cat.aar` & `fish.aar` for simplicity.

`cat.aar` supports 64 bit. It has both armeabi-v7a & arm64-v8a related `.so` files.
cat aar library does n't include `.so` files in aar, I have to place them under application jniLibs.

`fish.aar` does n't have explicit support for 64 bit. It has only armeabi and armeabi-v7a related `.so` files. fish aar library has`.so` files also in the aar.

**My Problem**

I am able to use cat or fish aar independently in my app and my app is running fine on 32 bit and 64 bit devices.

When I include both cat & fish aar and `.so` files related to cat lib under application jniLibs folder, fish lib is trying to access its `.so` files under application jniLibs folder but not in its own aar. As a result, App is crashing with error `.so file not found` under libs whenever I invoke fish lib api. Whereas app is running fine as long as I use only cat lib api but not fish lib.

See below for my build.gradle file. Please guide me what changes I need to do in build.gradle so that I am able to use both cat & fish aar in my app.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    sourceSets {
        main {

            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.samples.fish.fishexplore"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    compile(name: 'cat', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'fish', ext: 'aar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'

}
```

Comment: Extract the apk and paste the directory sturcture with contents of these library?

Answer (score 1):

With Steady mind, I realized that there is no `.so` files scope changing concept. No mater whether you put `.so` files under libs or in .aar package,  in the apk file all these are packaged under

```
app-debug\libs\<arm64-v8a> or <armeabi> or <armeabi-v7a> or other ABI folder.
```

This is the place any aar or jar will look for its `.so` files from the `.apk`.

The reason for my application crash is - both cat & fish aar libs are using `opencv.so` files. cat libs has trimmed version of it and when fish lib has whole `opencv.so`. So, while packaging apk - fish's `opencv.so` will not get merged into libs as libs already has cat's `opencv.so` with the same name.
As a result, fish lib unable to find some of the required references in that.